# Underscore JavaScript find value exists for key in complex Object

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, underscore.js

I have the following JSON format which is dynamic i.e., number of children can be different at anytime.

```
var Obj = {
    "name": "A",
    "count": 13,
    "children": [{
        "name": "B",
        "count": 24,
        "children": [{
            "name": "C",
            "count": 35,
            "children": [],
            "msg": null
        },{
            "name": "D",
            "count": 35,
            "children": [],
            "msg": "Err"
        }]
    }]
}
```

How can we find if msg is not null in entire object Obj? I tried to use loop through objects but this format is not consistent as children array in the object is dynamic.I am new to underscore, Is there anyway to check with Underscore JavaScript?

Comment: Are you looking for pure js solution also or just underscore.js solution?

Comment: Anything is fine

Comment: What do you want your function to return? Is it some sort of array of objects that has property `name` where message is null or something like that?

Comment: Can you clarify: you want to determine if there are literally any instances of a child having a non-null msg? Or do you want to know if ALL of the msg are non-null?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly...

```
var anyMsgNotNull = (_.filter(Obj.children, function(child) {
    return (child.msg !== null);
  })).length > 0;
```

This will return true if there are any msg elements that are not null, otherwise it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

In plain js you can create recursive function using `for...in` loop that will return false if property with key `msg` and value `null` is found otherwise it will return `true`

```js
var Obj = {"name":"A","count":13,"children":[{"name":"B","count":24,"children":[{"name":"C","count":35,"children":[],"msg":null},{"name":"D","count":35,"children":[],"msg":"Err"}]}]}

function notNull(obj) {
  var result = true;
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (i == 'msg' && obj[i] === null) result = false;
    else if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') result = notNull(obj[i]);
    if (result == false) break;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(notNull(Obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Underscore the library which can help out like this:-

```
_.each(Obj.children,function(item){ //it will take item one by one and do 
                                    //  processing
  if(item.msg){
      //DO YO THING
   }
   return;
})
```